# Feldheim's Sefer Piyutim

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, song-poetry, prayer-book

Feldheim used to publish a book with the piyutim added for shabbatot throughout the year, which I have heard referred to by such disparate names as "the blue book"*,  *Piyutim le-shabatot ha-shana le-fi minhag Ashkenaz* ** and *Piyutim lechol shabbat beshabbato** **. Does anyone know the ISBN or locations on the internet where it might be found for sale?

---

*From an article on Shnei Zeitim originating on KAYJ.net

**cf. *ibid.*

***From an email exchange with R' Wallis Wiesenthal

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely one in a library in Denmark and in Regensburg (kind of close to you?)
http://www.worldcat.org/title/piyutim-le-shabatot-ha-shana-le-fi-minhag-ashkenaz-piyyutim/oclc/466173928

http://www.worldcat.org/title/piyyutim-las-sabbatot-has-sana-le-pi-minhag-askenaz-liturgical-poems-for-the-years-special-sabbaths-piyyutim/oclc/632462311

I think the ISBN number is 9780873062992 or possibly 087306299X 9780873062992.

The ISBN number implies that these two are the same book 
(translated), but I am not certain.

http://www.biblio.com/9780873062992

http://www.isbns.sh/isbn/9780873062992

They sell the translated one for $79 - $83

Comment: Actually, I'm in the US, my family's yichus is from Frankfurt (hence the screenname)